# Dependency injection as a rule?

Tags: inheritance, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I am trying to write a parsers system for poker hands history. Some will use regular expressions, other will use XML, and so on...

Currently I have this:

```
abstract class Parser {

    abstract protected GameContext findGameContext();

    public void parse() {
      GameContext gameContext = findGameContext();
    }    
}
```

And:

```
class RegexParser {
    protected GameContext findGameContext() {
        // find game context by using some regex...
    }
}
```

I am quite happy with it. If I want another kind of parser, I subclass Parser and I implement the abstract methods.
But, I know I can do the same using dependency injection.
Something like this:

```
class Parser {

    private IDataType<GameContext> gameContextFinder;

    public setGameContextFinder(IDataTypeFinder<GameContext> finder) { this... = ... }

    public parse() {
        GameContext gameContext = this.GameContextFinder.find();
        ...
    }
```

Where:

```
interface IDataTypeFinder<T> {
    public T find();
}

class GameContextFinder implements IDataTypeFinder {
    public GameContext find() {
        // some regex...
    }
}
```

And:

```
class RegexParser extends Parser {

    public RegexParser() {
        this.setGameContextFinder( new GameContextFinder() );
    }                                        
}
```

What do you think of both ways? 
So far I found DI useful for unit testing.
But the abstract inheritance feels more "natural"...

Comment: I think the first approach is better and cleaner. Also first approach is unit testable here. There is no need for dependency injection in first approach. You can mock parser as well as context easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what a "game context" contains and I don't understand why the parser needs one. But, I would have something outside the parser find the game context and inject it into the base parser class. Each subclass parser could use that context as they desire.

I prefer to keep several classes that are parsers but they all subclass the main `Parser` class or all implement the `Parser` interface. (In the interface case, we usually use a `BaseParser` or `ParserImpl` class in we need a root class.)

Then, where you use the parser you keep a variable that holds it:

```
public UsingParserClass {
    private Parser theParser;

    public setParser(Parser val) { theParser = val;}
}
```

And it will have more methods to do the actual work.

Then you inject the desired subclass into the instance of the `UsingParserClass` using the setter. Different dependency injection frameworks do that in various ways. Or you can just use your code to do it.

You also find the game context and inject it into the parser from that same place.

```
... some setup code somewhere ...

myUsingParserClass.setParser(new RegexParser());
myUsingParserClass.getParser().setGameContext(gameContextFinder.find());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. GameContext is an enum, it could be any info related to the game (variant, limit, nb players...) that the parser wants to extract from the hands history.